# How to add custom payment module in Magento?

Tags: payment-methods, payment, magento-1.9.4.1

How to add custom payment module in Magento_1.9.4.1

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials are available for creating Payment method:

Here are some of them:

https://www.codealist.com/magento-1-9-create-custom-payment-method/

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/28/magento-create-custom-payment-method/

Also, you can use the basic payment module that will create a basic Payment method.

https://github.com/llapgoch/magento-custom-payment-method

You can customize this to add your required payment method details.

Answer (score 0):

Download a sample extension from here:

[download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pjGaPi46lqt-RTe4Jotu-bxgoiDwlbWT/view?usp=sharing)